# ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version

Tags: python, pandas, pip, easy-install, python-dateutil

I'm facing this issue while trying to use pandas package. I have installed numpy 1.9.0 and installed dateutil 2.5.0 using the command 
`pip install python-dateutil==2.5.0`. Still I see this error.

Is there any other way to install dateutil? And this is related only to pandas package

> Traceback (most recent call last):    import pandas as pd   File
>   "/Users/xyz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from pandas.compat.numpy import *   File "/Users/xyz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/compat/**init**.py",
>   line 422, in 
>       raise ImportError('dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version') ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version

Comment: what is the output of `which python` ?

Comment: And what is the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: python 2.7 and pip 18.0

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using the newest pandas version, try downgrading to pandas 0.22.0 which fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by installing python 3.6. There is a version compatibility issue between pandas package and earlier version of Python

Comment: i am still getting the error after i upgrade from python 2.7 to 3.7. Any suggestion what i can do? just started python last week

Answer (score 0):

Check what code you used to run the program
I first tried running the file with: "python file.py"
but I got an error. so try running the file with

```
python3 file.py
```

(put your file name instead of the file)
This fixed the error and I was able to run the file